# Why is move_uploaded_file not working for me

Tags: php

I am using mysqli procedural programming and the move_uploaded_file isnt working for me now. I am working locally now so I have all privileges needed.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 
    redirectTo($settings['siteDir'] . 'admin/cpanel/');
}
```

I have never had problems before now. Is it the mysqli that is messing things up?
These are the errors I am getting

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/websites/mugendo.ie/images/uploads/mai.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\mugendo.ie\admin\addnews.php on line 29

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\php1498.tmp' to 'http://localhost/websites/mugendo.ie/images/uploads/mai.jpg' in D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\mugendo.ie\admin\addnews.php on line 29
```

Comment: No, and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you check directory permissions ?

Comment: I have made an edit to the question to to show the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `$target` should be a path

The second argument for [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is expected to be a path. The error message reads:

> Unable to move ... to `http://localhost/websites/mugendo.ie/images/uploads/mai.jpg`

As such, right now `$target` is a url. Provide a valid file path for `$target` and it will work, or provide a different error message e.g.:

```
$target = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\mugendo.ie\images\uploads\mai.jpg';
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 
    redirectTo($settings['siteDir'] . 'admin/cpanel/');
}
```

Be sure to read the error log if it fails - the error message will say exactly what needs correcting to succeed.

Comment: Yes i figured that out, i was using a $var['siteDirectory'] to show the location and forgot it would become a url